# can not update user asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

i have this code in my Account.aspx file:

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="user_lbl" runat="server" Text="Username:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="user_txt" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="email_lbl" runat="server" Text="Email:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="email_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="save_btn" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="save_btn_Click" 
            onclientclick="save_btn_Click" />
```

and this is what happens after you click on save-btn:

```
MembershipUser user;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        user = Membership.GetUser(Page.User.Identity.Name);
        user_txt.Text = user.UserName;
        email_txt.Text = user.Email;
    }

    protected void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!email_txt.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                user.Email = email_txt.Text;
                Membership.UpdateUser(user);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

but this does not change the email in database. why is that? 
i want the user to be able to change their email. how can i do that?

Comment: Where does your user variable come from? And why are you catching the exception and then just throwing it again?

Comment: @cbp no i mean i'm already using the answer to that question and it doesn't work

Comment: don't think about the exception now. i want to know why i can't change the email?

Comment: @zahramoradi: you didn't get any exception ?

Comment: it seems like when you click on save button then postback happen so it will call the pageload again and overwrite your changes with default and then save method call so it's save the same value not updated value

Comment: @DhavalPatel what can i do about it?

Comment: @zahramoradi:see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems like when you click on your button then Postback happen and again `page_load` event occur so it will overwrite your changes and store the same value in database so you can use the below mentioned code which can reslove your problem.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                user = Membership.GetUser(Page.User.Identity.Name);
                user_txt.Text = user.UserName;
                email_txt.Text = user.Email;
            }
```

Comment: @zahramoradi:upvote it and Happy coding :)

Comment: i can't upvote it. don't have enough reputation. put i chose it as the accepted answer. tnx again

Comment: @zahramoradi: ok make the reputation after all your are a IT gal :)

Comment: @zahramoradi: if you spend 1 hour every day you will learn many things as well as you can help the other people

Comment: It might be useful to explain *why* this works, don't provide code without any explanation.

Comment: @DGibbs: yes I have already explain her see the comments of Questions :)

Comment: @DhavalPatel It should feature in your answer, not everybody reads the comments.

Comment: @DGibbs: Ok I have updated my answer Thanks :)